# Restful WCF IIS 7.5 405 Method Not Allowed Intermittent

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-4.0, iis-7.5, http-status-code-405

I recently added some functionality to our WCF restful api compiled in .NET 4.0  hosted in our own web server using IIS 7.5.  When I'm testing in postman it works for awhile, then I start receiving 405 Method not allowed errors.  If I wait a period of time (nothing specific), then it will work for a few calls, then start over again.

After some searching, my best guess is we have some sort of handler mapping issue, but I don't know why all of a sudden we would as we haven't changed anything in IIS for quite some time.

I've tried what some others suggested in other questions such as the following:
(snipped of my web.config) and these haven't worked to resolve the issue.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>

<remove name="ServiceModel" />

<handlers>
      <remove name="svc-Integrated" />
      <add name=".svc" verb="*" path="*.svc" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, 
        System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
```

I should note that we are using .svc-less WCF (unsure if this is the correct terminology, but we don't have .svc files).

The website this application is in, is within a .NET 4.0-Integrated application pool.

When I look at the Handler Mappings within IIS, I see duplicates for "*", "*.", and "*.svc", but I have no idea what should and what should not be there.  Here is what I see for .svc listed in IIS.

[image: IIS svc Listing]

one thing I haven't done as I'm nervous to do so is:

> fire up your Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt or browse to "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\ v4.0.30319". And run the following command from the command prompt:  aspnet_regiis.exe -iru

I'm open to suggestions here, and I will gladly provide more details, but just not sure what else I can add at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far what has worked for me was clearing the RoutTable in our "InitializeService.cs" file.

```
RouteTable.Routes.Clear();
RouteTable.Routes.Add(......)
RouteTable.Routes.Add(......)
```

I don't know if something got cached in our IIS 7.5 server, or what the root cause of this is/was, but everything else I tried, nothing worked and after clearing the routes before adding them, I haven't had a 405 error.

Maybe someone else will find this helpful.